# Aggregate income

Tags: macroeconomics

Aggregate income is composed of:
• Employee compensation including wages and benefits.
• Rent for the use of property.
• Interest earned on funds loaned out.
• Profits earned by businesses.

Where are income for selling fixed assets and raw materials?
Why they don't included in aggregate income?

Comment: Income for selling raw materials consists of wages and profits, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

In the profits of the businesses selling fixed assets and raw materials.